# How to show '@' in title with gnuplot and the output format is png?

Tags: png, special-characters, gnuplot

Do you know how to show the character '@' in the title when using gnuplot and the output format is PNG image?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post an example script that causes this problem?  What kind of error/odd behavior do you see?

Comment: Does it work if you try different fonts?  Perhaps you need to set `GDFONTPATH` and use a proper font. -- Also, what happens if you try the `pngcairo` terminal?  If you have it installed, I find that it produces better output than the old png-gd version.

Comment: set term png enhanced size 1280,1024. It seems the 'enhanced' is the problem. After remove it, it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of gnuplot are you using?  Using gnuplot 4.4.3 with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set term png 
set output 'plot@.png'

set xlabel 'xlabel is @'
set ylabel 'ylabel is @' 
set title "title is @a\'\@\'a\@"

plot x t 'line title is @'
```

gives me this image:
[image]

Even playing with escape sequence characters doesn't seem to pose a problem, and the file created has an '@' in the filename.

Comment: Thanks andyras. I found where is the problem. Maybe 'enhanced' terminal cause the problem.

Comment: @PeilinYang -- `enhanced` does cause a problem with `'@'` (`@` creates a "phantom box".  See `help enhanced` for details).  If you're using enhanced text, then you need to escape your `'@'` -- e.g. `'\@'`