# How is @ produced in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, title, symbols

I'm trying to put as the title of a plot "P@10" using GnuPlot, using the Helvetica font.

What I did was this:

> set encoding iso_8859_1
>
> set title "P \100 10"

The \100 comes from the octal representation of the at symbol in [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0040/index.htm). The final plot, however, replaces the @ with a simple space. Other symbols work as expected.

I also tried the matlab script provided [here](http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=629%3asymbols-in-gnuplot&catid=48%3aengineering&Itemid=69), to look for the @ symbol in at least 4000 different codes, but I couldn't find it.

Is this possible, even with another font?

EDIT: I tried this on three different systems, Ubuntu AND Windows, to no avail..

EDIT2: Minimal working example:

> set term postscript eps enhanced color
>
> set encoding iso_8859_1
>
> set title "Test \@ Test" -or-     set title "Test \100 Test"
>
> set out "example.eps"
>
> plot sin(x)

My output doesn't have any @ sign in the title.

Comment: @choroba Do you suggest to maybe reinstall the fonts? Can you point me to something?

Comment: Which terminal are you using?  Can you post a minimal example script?

Comment: I'm using this: "set term postscript eps enhanced color". Adding an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144394/how-to-show-in-title-with-gnuplot-and-the-output-format-is-png/) may be helpful.  If you are using an 'enhanced' terminal you have to escape ('\@') the @ symbol.

Comment: This is almost certainly the culprit.  `@` is a meta-character in enhanced mode.  (`help enhanced`) should provide more details.

Comment: I already tried, instead of putting the octal code, to simply write the at symbol excaped, but the effect was the same.

Comment: Thanks for posting the example code.  I think the problem may now be your quotes.  Try `set title "Test \\@ Test"` or `set title 'Test \@ Test'`.  Those work for me.  With single quotes '\@' escapes the @ symbol, while with double quotes you have to escape the backslash itself in order for it to escape the '@'.  This is because of how gnuplot processes quoted strings.  In double-quoted strings escapes are interpreted by gnuplot before being sent to the terminal driver (as I understand it), while single quotes are ordinary literal strings to gnuplot.  `help syntax quotes` for more details.